# why is minimum value from stringArray using colections.min() not working?

Tags: android

I've been using this method to find the minimum value of doubleArray :

```
colections.min()
```

but when i'm using this method to string Array, it got the wrong result. Likes this :

My stringArray value : `{2.3 Km, 10,0 Km, 4.0 Km, 24,7 Km}`

but when i call the result, its show `10.0 Km` as minimum value instead `2,3 Km`.

Can anybody tell me what is the perfect method that i can use to get the minimum value of the srtringArray ?

I know this is a very basic question, but i really need more explanation.
Thank you

Comment: Of course it does.  A string beginning with `1` comes before a string beginning with `2`.  Just as it would with `A` and `B`.  The minimum value of a string array is the string which comes first alphabetically.  What are you expecting?

Comment: sorry. i just dont know. thankyou for your explanation.

Comment: @Simon, you should put that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string beginning with `1` comes before a string beginning with `2`. Just as it would with `A` and `B`. The minimum value of a string array is the string which comes first alphabetically. What are you expecting?